# How to Add AutoSlide effect to a specific image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, elastislide

I am new to jquery and i need help with an image gallery.I have choosen to use the gallery https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/ and what i want to do is to add the option of Auto slide for that gallery.The code is here : https://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/20/responsive-image-gallery/.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this plugin has an autoplay option, but I could be wrong. You can use `setInterval` to go to the next slide every two seconds if you want:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('.rg-image-nav-next').click();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,it solves the problem.I am using that gallery on a Bootstrap webpage and when i add the gallery to this bootstrap webpage it doesn't work.Do you have any idea if javascript from gallery does a crash with bootstrap.js???

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad it worked. I've tested bootstrap with that gallery plugin and it seems to work fine. This link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/17961bfbe9f98cc3e84d3b281ae2fd5a20161216082531/0345e4 contains a full bootstrap and responsive image gallery code I've made to test it and it works. You can download it. Also, do you have any errors in your console?